# hubProxy.broadcastMessage not being called in Java SignalR Client

Tags: java, signalr, signalr.client

I have hosted a SignalR server on ASP.net MVC website.

I connected a WinForms application as Client to this Server and that was working absolutely fine.

Now I made a Java client with the help of this [code](https://github.com/SignalR/java-client). This client connects successfully to the server, however when I send any message from the Server to this Client, it doesn't receive it.

The code for Java client is :

```
private static void ConnectSignalR() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException
{
      IP = GetExternalAddress();

      String ServerURI = "http://localhost:59044"; 
      hubConnection = new HubConnection(ServerURI); 
      hubProxy = hubConnection.createHubProxy("ChatHub");

      SignalRFuture<Void> con  = hubConnection.start(new ServerSentEventsTransport(hubConnection.getLogger())); //Or LongPollingTransport

        con.get(); 

        Object[] oa = new Object[] {"Win", UUID.randomUUID(), 5, IP}; 

        hubProxy.invoke("Notify", oa);

      hubProxy.on("broadcastMessage", new SubscriptionHandler2<String,String>() {
          @Override
          public void run(String e1,String e2) {
             System.out.println(e1.toString()); 
             checkMessage(e1, e2);
          }
        }, String.class, String.class);

      hubConnection.received(new MessageReceivedHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(final JsonElement json) {
                checkMessage("", json.toString());
            }
        });

}
```

So it never hits the breakpoint on broadcastMessage. What I might be doing wrong?